# Collections as Assets (3.1.1)

Tags: collections, asset-browser

In Blender version 3.1.1 I have a collection of parts of an object with a data structure something like this:

+-- Dandelion
      +-- leaf.01
      +-- leaf.02
      +-- petals
      +-- stem

My problem is I cannot mark the collection as an asset. One of the solutions that I have found is to instantiate the collection and marking it as asset (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFX8Fzg5CYY); then I am allowed to pull it in other blender scenes. However, through this method no thumbnail is appearing on the asset browser. Which is a problem since I do recognize items by thumbnails rather than names.

I appreciate any help regarding this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, what Blender version are you using ?

Comment: hey, thanks for reminding I always forgot that I am using 3.1.1 fixed on the original question as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've already discovered, *Collection*s are not integrated into the *Asset Browser* as of yet. Marking a collection instance is more of a hack than [a supported workflow](https://developer.blender.org/T95569), and thumbnails not being generated is a limitation of that hack so there isn't much you can do about it I'm afraid. Support for *Collection*s and other data-blocks is a [work in progress](https://developer.blender.org/T79178) though, so hopefully we'll get it soon enough. In the meantime, you can add custom thumbnails to your instances from the <kbd>N</kbd> panel:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I can set them manually until it is implemented. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Mimayuki FYI, Collections (with automatic thumbnail renders) are now officially supported in 3.2: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/collection-assets-feedback/23789

Comment: It came faster than I thought. Thanks for the notification. :)